# Why is T[] trivially copyable but not trivially destructible?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

First of all, what is the correct term for `T[]` (not `T[12]` and not `T*`)?

Second, if `T` is both trivially copyable and trivially destructible, why is `T[]` trivially copyable but not trivially destructible? I know it is for bounded arrays (`T[12]`).

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9frzob)

Comment: These are [arrays of unknown bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Arrays_of_unknown_bound).

Comment: i dont know about the details, so no answer just comment, but [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) mentions it explicitly: "If T is ..., or an array of unknown bound, value equals false". Didnt check the standard, but it seems like thats just how it is defined

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've overlooked this. Interestingly enough, it also applies to `std::is_destructible`.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `using element = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(T{}[0])>;` you could do `using element = std::remove_extent_t<T>;` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, what is the correct term for T[]

It is an array of unknown bound (shortened to AOUB below).

---

> Why is T[] not trivially destructible?

Standard (latest draft):

> [meta.unary.prop]
>
> Trait: is_­trivially_­destructible
>
> Condition: is_­destructible_­v is true and ...

> Trait: is_­destructible
>
> Condition: Either T is a reference type, or T is a complete object type for which ...

An AOUB is neither a reference type, nor is it a complete type. Thus it does not have the trait `is_­destructible` and thus it has `is_trivially_destructible` neither.

---

> Why is T[] trivially copyable

Standard (latest draft):

> [meta.unary.prop]
>
> Trait: is_trivially_copyable
>
> Condition: T is a trivially copyable type ([basic.types])

> [basic.types.general]
>
> Arithmetic types ..., arrays of such types, and ... are collectively called trivially copyable types.

Note that there is no exception for arrays of unknown bound. They are trivially copyable too according to this rule.

Comment: Hmm but how is it trivially copyable then?

Comment: @Timo The array pointer is trivially copyable - but I'm not sure that the array itself is. Can you give an example of how you do the trivial copy?

Comment: @fredrik I don't. This is more about why `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T[]> == true` while `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T[]> == false`. And `T[]` is **not** the pointer, that would be `T*`.

Comment: @Timo Then without any reference for it, I'm going to assume (until someone says otherwise) that it is trivially copyable because it will only copy the pointer - not what it's pointing to.

Comment: @Timo Added standard quotes.

Comment: I wonder what the committee's reasoning behind this specification was. I get that, because it's an incomplete type, it isn't trivially destructible (and neither trivially constructible iirc). On the other hand, how can it be trivially copyable then? Is this a defect?

Comment: @Timo I don't know how closely they have considered the case. They've at least explicitly specified that AOUB are valid arguments for these traits. It could be something that doesn't really matter.